# Why does the Flickr public feed API return "undefined" before displaying photo results when accessed by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I started working with APIs/Ajax/JSON recently and began a small project to test my knowledge.

I made a simply website where you type a word into a form and it brings back Flickr photos associated with the word.

It works pretty well, but it always includes a simple "undefined" before the first photo which messes with the display of the first row of pictures.

An example can be seen here, simply search for a photo tag and you'll see what I'm talking about:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPExNm

Here is the related jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
// the AJAX part
var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
var query = $('#photoQuery').val();
var flickrOptions = {
  tags: query,
  format: "json"
};
function displayPhotos(data) {
  var photoHTML;
  $.each(data.items,function(i,photo) {
    photoHTML += '<div class="photo">';
    photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link + '" class="image">';
    photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '"></a></div>';
  }); // end each
  $('#photoGallery').html(photoHTML);
}
$.getJSON(flickerAPI, flickrOptions, displayPhotos);

}); // end submit
```

I haven't found any errors related to this in the Javascript console and couldn't find anything like this while Googling, so I'm turning to StackOverflow. Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
var photoHTML;
```

is the same thing as

```
var photoHTML = undefined;
```

Basic example of what you are doing

```
var str;
str = str + "123"; // undefined + "123" = "undefined123";
```

You need to set it to an empty string

```
var photoHTML = "";
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdNMNw working example with the above mentioned change

Comment: Ahh, damn. I knew it'd be something stupid like that. Thank you very much!